# Why are they connecting the input signal parallel to the dc source?

Tags: amplifier, common-emitter

My textbook says the voltage across \$BE\$ would be \$0.7+v_i\$. But this looks incorrect to me based on the shown circuit. It seems the \$v_i\$, \$V_{BB}\$, and the base diode are in parallel. We are connecting an ac source in parallel with a dc source. Isn't this kind of a contradiction ? Some how *I don't really see how the input ac signal superimposes over 0.7*. We should not connect voltage sources of different values in parallel right ? Appreciate any help. Thank you !

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzKPTb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So your textbook actually shows a 2V power rail attached to the base of the transistor? Either it's a misprint or you've drawn this up wrongly, since otherwise it's a bog standard Class A amplifier.

Comment: Yeah, in the emitter bias my textbook uses only the emitter resistor. Base is simply connected to VBB. No base resistor. May I know how putting a resistor in series with VBB fix anything ? Still I don't see how \$v_i\$ superimposes on \$0.7\$ :[

Comment: @Chu I think it is bothering me because I feel \$v_i\$ should be placed in series with \$VBB\$, then only the input signal can superimpose with the dc 0.7 ? I know my thinking is flawed somewhere, I don't clearly see my error as of now

Comment: Where is this circuit from? VBB places a low impedance across the signal. Adding a bias voltage and signal at a junction is not an issue as long as the DC bias arrangement does not load the signal source unduly.

Comment: This particular circuit is from Malvino 6th edition. May be a printing mistake. I've seen couple earlier. I have another slightly different example, I'll update the circuit. One sec :)

Comment: @Chu I have updated the circuit. This is giving correct simulation results xD. I have a really stupid question : If I connect a voltage source across a resistor, the voltage across that resistor will be same as the supply voltage. In my circuit, I'm connecting \$v_i\$ to BE, I expect the voltage to be \$v_i\$. Why am I seeing \$0.7+v_i\$ across BE ?

Comment: In the circuit, I am applying the signal \$v_i\$ directly across \$BE\$. The signal voltage should force \$BE\$ to be same as \$v_i\$ right ?

Comment: The signal is between base and ground. If you have the scope set to DC you'll see the DC bias plus signal.

Comment: Emitter (E)  is ac ground in my circuit ?

Comment: Yes, but not DC ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The voltage at the base is \$V_{BE} +vi\$ because you add a large capacitor C1 in series with the input signal. The big/large capacitor for the AC signal behaviors just like a DC voltage source. And this voltage source provides DC level shifting. 
[Understanding this AC coupled circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301921/understanding-this-ac-coupled-circuit/301938#301938)

Comment: Ohhh that C1 has been charged to 0.7V, so the input signal simply floats on this 0.7V. Crystal clear now XD Thank you!

Comment: I've been mentally opening C1 for dc, shorting it for ac, and completely forgot that it is charged to 0.7V. Now I see my error. Thanks again :)

Comment: The voltage the base will be larger than 0.7V thanks to Re resistor. $$V_B = \frac{V_{cc} - V_{BE}}{\frac{R_B}{\beta +1}+R_E} * R_E + V_{BE}$$

Comment: You've applied KVL in the base circuit to arrive at that right ? so C1 actually charges to VB (the thevenin voltage at base) : voltage drop across R_E + diode drop. Awesome!

Comment: «*The big/large capacitor for the AC signal behaviours just like a voltage source*» Heck! No! A large enough capacitor in AC small signals acts like a *short circuit*, not a voltage source.

Comment: @Nasha But DC voltage source is a short circuit for AC signals too.

Comment: @Hiiii Yes, the KVL VB = Ie*Re + Vbe

Comment: I see nothing wrong with treating C1 as a voltage source in the present context. It is shifting the average value of input signal from 0 to base voltage just as a voltage source would. @Nasha

Comment: @G36 your answer is misleading because AC and DC analysis cannot be mixed in that capacitors are **shorts in AC** (small signals) and **open circuits in DC** so either you account for DC or AC, not both at the same time. Besides using the expression "*voltage source*" suggests it should appear as a *voltage source* somewhere in the analysis, which is incorrect. In fact it's the other way around: the constant voltage sources in the circuit result in a constant voltage difference on the capacitor pins; refer to the [equivalent circuit analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_circuit).

Comment: @Hiiii Another point of view (superposition less misleading ) https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/biasing-techniques-bjt/

Comment: @Nasha So, how would you explain the fact that the voltage at the base is VB + vi ? And explain the C1 capacitor role in "voltage shifting"? Also, the charged capacitor will in fact behave just like poor's man DC voltage source.

Answer (score 4):

A practical version of the Class-A amplifier might generate the base-bias voltage this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8L9ZG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 12K and 2.7K resistor generates about 2V. The equivalent Thevenin resistance is 12K in parallel with 2.7K (shown as R6). This resistance is missing from your rendition of the textbook schematic. Should be as shown in circuit snippet at right.

For calculating static bias, you might fix Vbe at 0.7V. However, the 1 MHz AC source will change this voltage (since this voltage source has zero resistance, its voltage is impressed at transistor's base). The capacitor from emitter to ground has a very low impedance at 1 MHz, which keeps the emitter nearly at a fixed DC voltage near 1.3V

Comment: Ahh that base resistor is missing in my textbook circuit. Makes sense now. C2 connects emitter to the gnd for ac, so all the "input signal + 0.7V" appears across the BE. Looks I'm finally understanding these. You guys are awesome! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I can see some confusion here due to mixing two analysis domains together: AC and DC. But first things first: circuit simplification.

### Equivalent DC circuit

In DC, capacitors are open circuits and **AC** voltage sources are replaced with shorts. So in the DC equivalent circuit, your schematics is reduced to just V<sub>cc</sub>, R<sub>1</sub>, R<sub>C</sub>, Q<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>E</sub>:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVeXSV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this reduced circuit, you can indeed view the base-emitter junction as a *constant* voltage source of about 0.7VDC.

### Equivalent AC circuit

In AC, constant (i.e. **DC**) voltage sources are reduced to zero (i.e. shorts) and capacitors are replaced with shorts. This means the 10VDC source **and** the base-emitter are **both** replaced with shorts, which reduces your schematics to the following equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgN33k.png)</sup>

### Putting it all together

*Stricto senso* there is no paralleling between V<sub>i</sub>, V<sub>BE</sub> or V<sub>CC</sub>, first because DC and AC voltage sources are analysed separately thus have separate effects but mostly because V<sub>i</sub> is separated from V<sub>CC</sub> through R<sub>1</sub> and because the 0.7VDC of the base-emitter junction does not play a significant enough role in AC — remember this is a simplification of a non-linear network, aka Q<sub>1</sub>, in which the non-linear response of the base-emitter diode is neglected *due to the small signal analysis*, i.e. assuming the base only sees realtively small signals, which keep the transistor in its linear region.

The DC analysis shows the voltage and current values that you'd measure using a multimeter set in DC, while the AC analysis shows the same but for the AC settings. The [superposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem) (between the AC and DC analysis) explains why the voltage on the base is \$ V_{BE}+v_i(t) \$ or \$ 0.7V + v_i(t)\$.

---

The fact is that theory doesn't really apply to your schematics because Q<sub>1</sub> is not properly biased and there's no negative feedback, which makes the transistor work outside its linear region.

The DC analysis in made even more complex because the base voltage depends on the collector current. R<sub>1</sub> value is such that the base current cannot be neglected and depends on \$ h_{FE} \$, which makes it even harder (though not impossible) to compute the quiescent current of the collector.

Moreover the circuit is highly dependent on Q<sub>1</sub>'s characteristics (mostly its h<sub>FE</sub> parameter) and may very be saturated, i.e. the collector-emitter voltage could fall below 0.7VDC. It will most probably result in a highly distorted output signal. See [glen_geek's response](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/310329/59864) for a proper biasing of the transistor. You might also connect R<sub>1</sub> between the base and collector for a negative feedback.