# Two ways to understand bypass capacitor to reduce supply ripple

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I knew two ways to understand how bypass capacitor reduces ripple, but I don't know how both these ways are related:

1)  A large capacitor stores a lot of charge; when supply fluctuates, the capacitor gives the charge and keeps the voltage almost constant.
2) A large \$C\$ means very less reactance. Thus all the ac is grounded.

I understand each of above two explanations very well. But I don't seem to see the connection between them. How are they same? In particular, `how storing a lot of charge is same as grounding ac`? Any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Simply, any AC signal (supply noise) present at the output of a voltage divider will be short to GND via big Cy capacitor (very low Xc)

Comment: Yes, how is `grounding ac` related to `being able to supply large amounts of charge`?

Comment: A big capacitor in the presence of a fast-changing AC signal will do not have time to charge or discharge. Therefore the voltage at the voltage divider output will be unchanged.

Comment: Oh interesting.. I need to review my basics never thought of it like this before...  But less reactance means a lot of current passes through the capacitor and thus the capacitor has to charge, right? I mean how can the capactor allow large current without charging?

Comment: The key here is the RC time constant must be much much larger than the AC signal period. Only in this case, the capacitor voltage will change very slightly compared to the AC signal amplitude. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301921/understanding-this-ac-coupled-circuit/301938#301938 or this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475

Answer (score 3):

The basic capacitor-charge-voltage formula is Q = CV or, charge equals capacitance multiplied by voltage.

We know that the rate at which charge (Q) changes is current hence, assuming the capacitor value is fixed we get: -

$$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

So, if the fluctuations (or AC or ripple) cause a bigger dv/dt then the current is bigger also. This means that rapidly changing fluctuations see a low impedance because the current is higher when fluctuations are more rapid.

Comment: Ahh large \$\frac{dv}{dt}\$ implies large current, hence low reactance. If the supply voltage drops to a low value briefly, then \$\frac{dv}{dt} \lt 0\$. Then the current is also negative. Hence the capacitor supplies its stored charge to the `load+source` in reverse. I'll think about this some more and get back. Thank you so much:)))

Answer (score 3):

The first case, of capacitor suppressing fluctuations in a supply voltage is relevant in a DC context. If the supply has no fluctuations, when the supply is connected the load would see the voltage rise up slowly (relative to what it would see without the capacitor) while the capacitor charges up, and then, when the capacitor has the same voltage as the supply, the load would see the full supply voltage. If the supply voltage fluctuates, the capacitor either charges up a bit or discharges a bit, in opposition to the change in supply voltage. While this happens, the load sees less of a change in the supply voltage because the capacitor compensates for the change. If the supply voltage stabilises at a different voltage however, the capacitor will become stably charged again, and the load will see the new voltage. In this sense, the capacitor can be seen as a low pass filter: it absorbs high frequency changes in voltage but allows low frequency changes to propagate.

In the second case you mention, the voltage is AC (or an AC signal riding on a DC base voltage). High frequency fluctuations in voltage are opposed by the capacitor less than low frequency changes in voltage, so for high frequency fluctuations the capacitor behaves like a short to ground and thus suppresses them. For low frequency fluctuations, the capacitor has a higher resistance, and therefore preserves them relative to ground.

A capacitor always has lower resistance w.r.t. higher frequencies, and vice versa, higher resistance w.r.t. lower frequencies. Whether it provides a low pass, or a high pass filter depends on whether it is the voltage *across* the capacitor (low pass) or across the rest of the circuit (high pass).

When a capacitor is used in an AC circuit, it is alternately storing and releasing charge. If the frequency is very low, then the capacitor could charge up a lot, then discharge and charge up a lot the opposite way alternately. But if the frequency is very high, there isn't much time to charge, so the maximum charge it obtains is lower. In the extreme, a DC circuit has frequency 0, so the capacitor charges fully and ends up being equivalent to a break in the circuit. At the other extreme, a very high frequency AC circuit wouldn't allow time for the capacitor to charge up at all in either direction, so the capacitor wouldn't oppose the current, and ends up being equivalent to a short in the circuit.

Comment: So clearly explained thank you so much:) If I may ask this silly q, with large C, the reactance is less and the current is large. Consider first quarter of the cycle. The capacitor allows huge positive current to pass through it. Doesn't this large current charge the capacitor heavily? Doesn't large current means large charge ?

Comment: @beccaboo V = Q/C ---> the large the capacitance C the smaller the voltage" change" for a given charge Q.

Comment: Large C means the capacitor requires more charge to reach a given voltage (and means the capacitor is physically bigger too, assuming it's made of the same materials). And yes, bigger C means lower reactance = Xc = 1 / (2 * pi * freq * C). The rest of the circuit will normally be limiting the maximum current though.

Comment: Oh cool feels I get it XD If we directly connect ac voltage source to a capacitor, the current increases as capacitance is increased. This happens because larger capacitance actually requires large charge to reach the same voltage. Since we're forcing the voltage to be the source voltage, the current must increase to charge the capacitor so that the capacitor tracks the source voltage `instantly`.Hope I got this rightXD Thanks to both of you. You're soo awesome<3

Comment: Yes, that would happen 'in theory'. In practice, the supply might not be able to support sufficient current due to its internal resistance, and the capacitor would likely burn out due to excessive current. If you have an AC supply, resistor, and capacitor in series, then the voltage across the capacitor is 90 degrees out of phase with the current through it because the capacitor is charging at maximum rate when the voltage across it is zero, the charge it stores is zero, and the current is peaking.

Answer (score 2):

Following up, with an example ---

Assume 60Hz power, ful-wave rectified to produce 120 Hz ruipple,

Assume you can accept 1 volt ripple at 1 amp load current.

What are the numbers?

Q = C * V, differentiated and assuming constant "C"

We have I = C * dV/dT

We want the Cvalue

re-arrange for C = I * dT / dV

and C = 1 amp * (1/120) / 1 = 1/120 farad or 0.008333 farad

or 8,333 microFarad