# How to calculate voltage across capacitor C1?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors, ac, phasor

If the voltage

\$v_I = \frac{jωC1R3}{1 + jωC1R3}*Vs \$

does that mean the voltage across the capacitor would be equal to \$v_S - v_I\$ ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please pay attention that _current_ is though. _Voltage_ is across.

Comment: The problem with though, through, thought, tough is that they all pass the spelling test.

Comment: Remember that in steady-state the average current through an ideal capacitor is always zero. And you can use a superposition to find the DC component and AC component separately. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301921/understanding-this-ac-coupled-circuit/301927#301927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage *across* the cap (not through it) is, by definition vS - vI. So yes.

Comment: Because the capacitor is DC blocking does that mean its voltage value will be the real part of the complex voltage?

Comment: The direct voltage across the capacitor will be the direct voltage present in \$\small v_s\$. The real part of \$\small v_s\$ is not the direct voltage, it's the in-phase component.