# Designing a BJT amplifier for a specific voltage gain

Tags: bjt, homework

Our teacher gave us a homework assignment to design a common-emitter amplifier.

My task is design an amplifier which has 12 voltage gain rate.

Firstly, I drew its small signal model, nd determined its voltage gain formula.

Then, I assumed some values. For instance RE, RS, RC, RL, \$\beta\$(beta) and tried to calculate R1 and R2 according to 12, voltage gain.

Unfortunately, when I calculate R1 and R2, the rate was negative. I said that is not possible because resistances are always positive. Unfortuntaley I couldn't make my homework but I want to learn what my problem is and what I did wrong.

My solution and question:

[image]

[image]

Comment: common emitter amplifier always results in an inversion between the input and output. The gain is negative.

Comment: .... Hence the gain is always negative.

Comment: Yes you are right but I used formula without its negative sign. @Paul

Comment: I can't read your handwriting so type in a comment what values you got.

Comment: RE = 500, RS = 1k RL = 24k RC = 12k VT = 27mV Ic = 2.4mA Av = 12 beta = 127 and I found R1 = R2 = 2.104k. Thank You @Andyaka

Comment: Yeah that looks about right for a gain of 12. Rs, R1 and R2 provide a 2:1 attenuation and  RL and RE provide a gain of 24.

Comment: So, you are saying your method and values is right ? Did you calculated all values like me or you used a programme ?

Comment: @Andyaka I have drawn my circuit by proteus but didn't work. I drew it by BC547

Comment: I used my brain. No pen nor paper nor electrons were harmed in the process. BJT gain is Rc/Re = 24. Equivalent resistance of input bias resistors is about 1 kohm (2x 2.104k in parallel) hence input AC signal is reduced by about 2:1 due to Rs being 1 kohm. RL will reduce the gain a bit below 12 of course.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but why doesn't work this circuit ? I drew same circuit but doesn't work. You can see the circuit https://hizliresim.com/gMsnEH

Comment: And Vcc is equal to?

Comment: Vcc is equal to 20V @G36

Comment: But did you forgot about Ohm's Law?  If Vcc is 20V and R1= R2 then the base voltage is 10V and the emitter voltage is 9.3V. Thus, Ie = Ic = 9.3V/500R = 18.6mA and because Rc is 12k IC_max = 20V/12k = 1.6mA. All this means that your BJT is saturated. And it will not work as an amplifier. You cannot randomly select the component values.

Comment: I didn't know what you said excatly. Yes you are right. After you, I changed emitter resistance with 36k but circuit didn't work again as an amplifier.

Comment: What exactly your teacher tells you to do? Did he specify the voltage gain value only? What about Vcc, Rs, and RL values?

Comment: @G36 Our teacher said you can chose all values and transistor should work on active region. I already couldn't make this homework accurately but I want to learn how I can make.

Comment: Well for Ic = 2.4mA and Rc =12k we have Ve =1.2V and V_Rc = 29V Thus, Vcc = 60V The gain will be around 8k/(1/gm + 500R) = 15V/V; Thus to get 12V/V we need to attenuation it by 0.8 or so. Thus, R1||R2 needs to be equal to around 2k. And at the same time, the voltage at the base needs to be equal to Ve+Vbe = 1.2V + 0.7V = 1.9V. So you need to choose R1 and R2 os that R1||R2 = 2k and Vcc*R2/(R1 + R2) =1.9V Can you do it?

Comment: @G36 I calculated R1 = 2k, R2 = 63k Result: https://hizliresim.com/9u96KD

Comment: Reduce the input signal amplitude.

Comment: @G36 I reduced up to 15mv and output was 90mV. Av = 6 also I replaced BC547 with more powerfull transistor and output was 800-900mV. Do you think there is a problem or it is normal ? İs 12 voltage gain rate so big ?

Comment: How did you measure this 90mV? And this 900mV for what output transistor?

Comment: And the voltage gain is not a problem, the problem lies in the fact that you decided to choose (pick) Rc and Ic randomly without consideration of the supply voltage influence.

Comment: Sorry I guess I write wrongly 900mV, it should be 120mV. I measured them by oscilloscope. Output is RC = 12k and RL = 24k in parallel. So what is criteria of designing amplifier ? I have resarched something about it and some resources say you should choose half current of saturation current. But I didn't understand why.

Comment: @Piko Strange, can you show the full schematics?

Comment: What capacitors values did you use? And the input signal frequency is?

Comment: @G36 https://hizliresim.com/vHMHq1
https://hizliresim.com/QO9w8D

With and without capasitor. I thought capasitor is not important because voltage gain doesn't depend on capasitor ? Can you also suggest me a resource to learn how bjt amplifier is designed excatly ?

Comment: @Piko The voltage gain will depend on the value of the capacitors. Because the capacitors together with corresponding resistors will form a high pass filter. Thus, it will set the amplifier's low cutoff frequency. So, only a signal with an input frequency larger than the amplifier lowers cutoff frequency will be amplified with the gain equal to 12V/V.

Comment: I set Vin = 1.41V peak at the input and F = 1kHz. Thus, at the output, I've got 12.1V RMS.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTk97.png  So, the gain is around 12.

Comment: Well, to be able to start the designing process we need to know the circuit requirements. The baisic ones are the voltage gain (desired voltage swing at the output ), the frequancy respons, the load resistance (what device receives our amplified),  input signal resistance and the amplifiude.

Comment: @G36 Thank you so much. You really helped me. I have learned a lot of things from you and this question. Why do we have to you capacitors or high-low pass filter ?

Comment: @Piko Well, the capacitor is needed because without it the input signal would upset the DC condition. Notice that we want the voltage at the base to be equal to +1.9V  But the input signal will have positive and negative voltage (for example +1V and -1V). And without a capacitor, the transistor will cut-off or change the DC operating point. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301921/understanding-this-ac-coupled-circuit/301938#301938

Comment: And we have a high pass filter because the capacitor blocks the DC and only passes AC signals. The higher the signal frequency the lower the capacitor resistance (capacitive reactance Xc). And in your circuit, the capacitors are in series with a "signal path", this is why we have a high pass filter (Xc at DC =00).