# Isn't conventional current supposed to go from high potential to low potential ? If yes, then why this rule is not respected in opamp using AC?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, ltspice

First, thank you for reading my post. I'm a beginner in electronics. I learned that conventional current goes from high potential to low potential. It has always worked for me in DC and even AC. But recently, i did see this rule being violated in AC, which i think is  impossible...right ? To give you an insight, i have to tell you that i'm working with opamps. Here is how i see current direction in a non-inverting opamp configuration:

[image]

In part A, the output is amplified by a positive gain but because the input is negative, the output becomes even more negative. So, at that moment, the lowest potential in the circuit is the ouput, then we have the inverting input of the opamp that is at same potential as the input, and finally the ground being at 0 volts is the highest potential. So conventional current would flow from ground to the output of the opamp(vice versa for part B). You can see why on the following graph :

[image]

So i tried it on Ltspice:

[image]

no problem it works. Current going through R1 gets positive and negative [-5mA:5mA] (so goes in the both directions periodically, so this is AC) :
[image]

When i add an offset as such:

[image]

Output is always greater than the input, current is then only positive [0:5mA]( so it's DC), so it works:

[image]

But when i try to add two capacitors in parallel with the two resistors (in the feedback) :

[image]

I still have the output always greater than the input, but this time, the current passing through the capacitors path is alternating between positive and negative :

[image]

Although, i have to note that because i did apply a DC offset at the input of the opamp, i have to provide it a path at the output for the DC current to pass through (the resistors path is doing that, just by looking at I_R1 we see that the current is always positive, so that's DC current).

I also understand that capacitors block any DC current so if something has to "pass through", it has to be alternative current. But still, think about it, i always have a greater electric potential at the output than the inverting input of the opamp, so current should flow from output to the inverting input of the opamp and then to the ground. So, it should be a DC current passing through the resistors only. But then it would mean that there is no voltage drop across the capacitors (since no current supposedly pass through the capacitors) which is impossible because we all know that the voltage drop across the capacitors are the same than the respective resistors because they are in parallel..

So.. Has the rule "Current goes from high potential to low potential" been violated ?

PS: Sorry for the long post and thank you for your precious time !

Edit : Here is the sum of the current I_R1 and I_Cact1

[image]

Comment: *Isn't conventional current supposed to go from high potential to low potential ?* No, the convention is that in a power consuming device (like a resistor), **current** flows from a high potential to a low potential. Realize that **electrons** do flow from high to low but that a current **by definition** flows in the opposite way. I stopped reading after the title as I see no point in reading further if it is not clear to you how current flows.

Comment: LTspice has to pick a reference current direction, and it can only be one way. Think of it like the current convention used in Kirchhoff's circuit laws. Simply rotate your resistor 180 degrees in the schematic and the current will be to your liking. Alternate: Download File:Res.asy and place in your /lib/sym folder. This symbol has a small arrow indicating the defined way current flows.  See this http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Most_frequently_asked_questions_for_beginners#Why_is_the_current_going_the_wrong_way_in_a_resistor.3F

Comment: Could you also plot I(R1)+I(Cact1) in the final plot ?

Comment: I think this rule that current is always along the potential gradient applies only to purely resistive components. Capacitors can have current in both direction regardless of the instantaneous DC voltage. The current through a cap is not proportial to its voltage, but instead to its dV/dt. So when you add reactive components to your circuit, you can see this "rule" violated.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie + G36 I think the point of the post is that the feedback current I(R1)+I(Cact1) alternates in sign although the feedback voltage is always positive.

Comment: This is quite confusing as there's a lot going on, but have you tried simply adding the other end of Cact to your voltage plot? You will then see what the voltage is on both ends.

Comment: TLDR - please get to the point.

Comment: @pjc50 the voltage at the other end of Cact is the same as Vin

Comment: @G36 thanks for the tip, i didn't know this one, but unfortunalely this is not the topic

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie conventional current flows from high potential to low potential, but charges from low to high (the "real life" direction). I don't think i did a mistake with that...

Comment: OK, I see but notice that I_R1 is in phase with Vout. So where is the problem?

Comment: @G36 Well, i don't really see what that has to do with the problem honestly. The problem i have here is that i see alternative current but have the output of the opamp always higher than all other electric potential in the circuit. So it should be DC not AC, there is no reason for the current to alternate, right ? Output always bigger than input so why current would go in the opposite direction...?

Comment: @AF2021 But the voltage at the output is constantly changing with the frequency of 40Hz. Thus, if DC voltage is "changing" with the frequency of 40Hz around 13.5V we have a AC component isn't it?

Comment: @G36 ok that's getting interesting. But AC (alternative current) only occurs because we happen to have low and high potential switching during time, isn't it ? Thus, current changes direction periodically. But here, voltages varies but never "exchange" their place as high or low electric potential... So we should have a non constant "current speed" through the capacitors BUT always same direction. No ?

Comment: @AF2021 no, at DC when Vin = 0V the Cact1 will be charged to 4.5 * (1 + 100/50) *100/150 = 9V (Vout 13.5V). Now, for a "positive swing" when Vout increases from 13.5V to a larger voltage (let us say to 14V) the Cact wants to change himself to the new value. But when output voltage decreases his value from a DC value 13.5V to the new value during "negative swing"  (let us say to 13V) Charged capacitor will now act just like a voltage source, and it will start a discharging process (The current will flow in the opposite direction).

Comment: Try to read this   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287394/ac-circuit-having-only-capacitor/287475#287475 and this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301921/understanding-this-ac-coupled-circuit/301938#301938

Comment: @G36 Thank you so much ! I think you are right. But you said that the capacitor will act as a "voltage source", you meant current source right ? I say that because in the link you kindly shared, the image of the author's book is mentionning (at the very top) that an alternative current is generated because of charging and discharging of the capacitor(which is your point i think). So it is a current source, right ? Also do you think that the alternative current i see on the capacitor is only made of the charging and discharging of the capacitor or is the output signal of the opamp added to it ?

Comment: @G36 I mean, are you saying that the alternating current signal through the capacitor i see on ltspice is only coming from the charge and discharge of the capacitor ?

Comment: The capacitor stores energy in form of an electrical field between its plates. Thus, if you disconnect the previously charged capacitor (say to 10V). The capacitor will "hold" the charge (and 10V) between its plates. And you can use the capacitor to "power" another circuit. So it definitely behaves like a very poors version of a voltage source.

Comment: "I mean, are you saying that the alternating current signal through the capacitor I see on ltspice is only coming from the charge and discharge of the capacitor" Yes, exactly only charge/discharge current.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122995/discussion-between-af2021-and-g36).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that conventional current is always along the potential gradient applies only to purely resistive components. Capacitors can have current in both direction regardless of the instantaneous DC voltage.

While the current through a resistor a proportial to its voltage, the current through a cap is not proportial to its voltage, but instead to its dV/dt.

So when you add reactive components to your circuit, you can see this "rule" violated

Comment: Thanks @tobalt, , i kinda "felt" that too. Even if it still seems weird to me that alternative current can be "produced" with such fixed electric potentials, i guess i will have to make an exception here...(btw i added the sum of current you ask for)

Comment: Enough points in the curves (cyan and grey) of the picture above ?